After compiling Qt and Webkit, compiling my app fails w: "cannot find -lWebKit1" but i see all the files in pkg config/lib/include that are needed
After nearly finishing compiling my app, it fails with error

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lWebKit1"

I compiled Qt with webkit manually. It completes properly, and I see all the necessary files created in libs/include/pkg-config, so I am unsure what the problem is. From what I can tell, the -lWebKit1 flag comes from Qt5WebKit.pc, located in my pkg-config database after compiling Qt with webkit. When I install libqt5webkit5-dev and libqt5webkit5 with aptitude, I don't get these errors. Do I need to export a path after the Qt compilation, and if so, which? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Compiling my app, I expected to complete, but it only completes when I install Qt and webkit with aptitude, not when I compile them manually.

What do you mean by "all the necessary files created in libs/include/pkg-config"? That would be an absolutely inappropriate place for most of the necessary files.  Or for all of the necessary ones, really, as it's only suitable for pkg-config files, and use of pkg-config is optional.  Did you install webkit when or after you built it?  If so, then what installation location did you choose, and / or did you accept a default location?

Your post is (to me at least) a bit confusing.  Please [edit] it to provide both the actual command line that generated the error and the complete error itself.  You might also want to provide the output of pkg-config --libs Qt5WebKit.

i compiled webkit in the qt compilation, by untaring the contents to a qtwebkit folder, and i watched it compile all of it succesfully. in my windows cross compile, i see all the qt libs/qtwebkit .dll files created, but im unsure as to why ld returns "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lWebKit1, /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lWebCore, /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lJavaScriptCore"  are these just options i need to add to the config when i compile qt and qtwebkit? these flags are not specified in my app, nor do they need to be.

Where suitable pre-packaged modules are available, such as from Aptitude, it is almost always preferable to use those instead of building the software yourself.  Are the packages from Aptitude inadequate for your purposes in some way?

And what does any Windows cross-compilation have to do with it?  If such a procedure is involved in your issue then you should be providing details in the question, but /usr/bin/ld is not a cross-linker, so it should not be emitting diagnostics pertaining to such a cross-build.  Overall, the errors described suggest that  WebKit probably is not installed correctly, and maybe not at all.  The same might apply to other components.

i see all the .dll files created in ubuntu after i compile qt/qtwebkit. of course i cant use aptitude, im compiling a windows app on ubuntu. i can compile it fine with aptitude for linux. thats what windows cross compilation has to do with it. im mentioning it because  you cant use aptitude qt and webkit to make a windows app on ubuntu.

That's just it, @user28302341: at the point where you get an error from /usr/bin/ld, your are not cross-compiling for Windows.  /usr/bin/ld is the system's native linker, not a cross-linker.  And pkg-config is probably irrelevent to cross-building, too.  But again, if you're trying to do a cross-build then you absolutely need to describe that in the question.  The exact commands you use to unpack the source (all sources), configure the build, and perform the build, and the exact (copy & paste) error messages produced would be in order.
